# Comparison Operator - Type Juggling and Booleans

Tags: php

I've been reading the PHP Docs on Type Juggling and Booleans but I still don't understand why this comparison evaluates as true. My [incorrect] understanding tells me that in the below *if* statement, the integer 0 is considered *FALSE* and "a", being a non-empty string is considered *TRUE*. Therefore, I expected this comparison to resolve to *FALSE == TRUE* and ultimately, *FALSE*. Which part did I get wrong?

```
   <?php
            if(0 == "a"){
                    $result = "TRUE";
            }else{
                    $result = "FALSE";
            }

            //$result == "TRUE"
    ?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/EjxBF5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When PHP does a string <=> integer comparison, it attempts to convert the string to a number in an intelligent way. The assumption is that if you have a string "42" then you want to compare the *value* 42 to the other integer. When the string doesn't start with numbers, then its value is zero.

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

This behavior is also inferred in the [comparison docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (look at the first line in the first example).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and helping my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you assume `operator ==` coerces each of its operands to boolean before comparing them. It does no such thing.

What happens is that since you are [comparing an integer to a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), the string is converted to an integer (in this case [`"a" converts to 0`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)) and then the comparison `0 == 0` is performed.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you use a strict comparison `===` instead of `==`. The strict comparison also checks the type of the variables, so `0 === 'a'` would be false.